# background image doesn't show up although has set the absolute and relative display for the tag

Tags: html, css, background-image

This is the html

```
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h2>Mountain Travel</h2>
        <nav>
            <li><a href="#">Tour</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </header>
    <section class="introduction">
        <div class="background-image" style="background-image: url(assets/image/main.jpg);" >

        </div>
        <div class="content-area">
            <h1>Mountain Travel</h1>
            <h3>Unmissable Adventure Tours Around The World</h3>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Contact Us Now</a>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.introduction.background-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;

}
.introduction{
    position:relative;
}
```

However, the image doesn't show up at all. I am sure that the url is correct. Could anyone help me with it?

Comment: Hi that's interesting I wonder if it's being hidden by something.

Comment: Your css isn't being applied to `.background-image` because you're missing a space in the declaration. Try `.introduction .background-image { ... }` (note the space between the two classes).

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with image path. By the way, it would be better to specify the background directly on CSS instead of inside tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first you don't have a valid `html` structure (your `nav` tag was not close). Secondly the `.background-image` is a child of `.introduction`. So to access it in css you will need to use `.introduction .background-image` and not `.introduction.background-image`:

```css
.introduction .background-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}

.introduction{
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>Mountain Travel</h2>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Tour</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav> <!-- Don't forget to close your nav tag-->
</header>

<section class="introduction">
  <div class="background-image" style="background-image: url(https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png);" ></div>

  <div class="content-area">
    <h1>Mountain Travel</h1>
    <h3>Unmissable Adventure Tours Around The World</h3>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Contact Us Now</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

I use in this example a reliable source (google logo) for your image path. So if in your example it's still not working maybe the source of the image is not the good one.

As mentionned by [@KoshVery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5724303/kosh-very) please don't forget that a `li` need to be in a `ul` or `ol` html tag.

Comment: Also `<li>` should be children of `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Comment: @KoshVery Right I didn't see it I will update it Thanks

Comment: @renesmith Ok well but that is another feature and has nothing to do with the actual question :) So please can `upvote` and `validate` this question Thanks ;)